# Is closed unit ball in $H^1(U)$ compact in $L^2(U)$? Is closed unit ball in $H_0^1(U)$ compact in $L^2(U)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $U$ be an open bounded smooth set in $R^n$, the closed unit ball in $H^1(U)$ is precompact in $L^2(U)$ by Rellich theorem, but is it closed in $L^2(U)$?

I try to use sequetial closedness since $L^2(U)$is metric space. Let $u_n$ be a sequence in closed unit ball $\{v\in H^1(U)| ||v||_{L^2}+||\nabla v||_{L^2}\le 1\}$, then letting $u_n$ converging to a limit $u$ in $L^2(U)$. Then by a result in Brezis' functional analysis book Chapter 9, if$1<p\le +\infty$, $u_n\in W^{1,p}$ and $u_n$ converges to a $u$ in $L^p$ with $||\nabla u_n||_{L^p}$ bounded, then $u$ is in $W^{1,p}$. So $u$ has weak derivative in $L^p$. So the question seems only to show the boundedness?
It seems that I have gotten the idea, letting $u_n$ is a subsequence with its weak derivative weakly convergent to some $w$ in $L^2$(due to reflexivity) and show $w$ is just the weak derivative of $u$ and using $||w||_{2}\le \liminf_n||\nabla u_n||_2$ which gives the derised boundedness result. Is the above correct?

If the above is correct, then what if $H^1(U)$ is replaced by $H_0^1(U)$?

After thinking for several hours I come to a trick. The above $u_n$ assumed in a closed unit ball of $H_0^1(U)$ is converging weakly to a $u$ in $ H^1(U)$. And then in a local convex topological vector space(Hausdorff), a convex set is closed strongly if and only if it's weakly closed. So It seems the closed unit ball in $H_0^1(U)$ is a convex set which fact means $u$ is in the weak closure of the ball so that it is in the strong closed unit ball. Thus it proves the case for $H_0^1(U)$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct and the reasoning for $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is the same.

Comment: @gerw The above seems working well for $H^1(U)$ for the boundedness of norm of $u$, I don't know how to show $u$ is indeed in $H_0^1(U)$, can $u$ be in $H^1(U)$ outside of $H_0^1(U)$? I am not sure.

Comment: No, because $H_0^1$ is a closed subset of $H^1$.

Comment: @gerw Please note that $u_n$ is approaching in $L^2$ norm so that it may be coming out of $H_0^1(U)$. However it seems I have solved this in the editted question. Is there any gap? Could you help me verify it?

Comment: Yes, this works!